# SyntaxError: missing :

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file that creates a contextual menu.

```
function textCM()
{
$('.text').contextMenu('context-menu-1', {
 'Context Menu Item 1 node level 1': {
            click: function(element){ printId(element.attr('id')); },
        },
 'Context Menu Item 2 node level 1': {
            click: function(element){ printId(element.attr('id')); },
        },
});
}
```

I am trying to make the function create the context menu dynamicly (send a list of parameters and add them in my function).
What I have did untill now looks something like this:

```
function textCM()
{
$('.' + arguments[0]).contextMenu('context-menu-1', {
    arguments[1]: {
        click: function(element) {  
            alert('Menu item 1 clicked' + element.attr('id'));
            },
        },
});
}
```

The first function works as expected, but in the second function I get an error

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

that is caused by the line

```
arguments[1]: {
```

I know there are other questions with same error, but, as far as I can tell, it's not the same problem. I just can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Stop putting commas after the last property of an object literal, IE doesn't like it. I'm not sure if that's the cause of your issue or not.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't helped. And I am using firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variable for names in [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

You need to create an object, and use [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets):

```
var menu = {};
menu[arguments[1]] = {
        click: function(element) {  
            alert('Menu item 1 clicked' + element.attr('id'));
            },
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
var foo = 'oof';

var obj = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

console.log(obj); //Object {foo: "bar"}
```

You won't get `{ oof: 'bar' }`, as javascript defines object keys like this. Hence if you want to use a DYNAMIC variable name, you can't use the "quick" way of creating objects. What you can do though, is this:

```
var foo = 'oof';

var obj = {}; //First create an empty opject
obj[foo] = 'bar'; //Then assign the key by using brackets - this will expand foo

console.log(obj); //Object {oof: "bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have dynamic keys like that, you need to build the object with bracket notation.

```
function textCM() {

    var obj = {};
    obj[arguments[1]] = {
        click: function (element) {
            alert('Menu item 1 clicked' + element.attr('id'));
        }
    };

    $('.' + arguments[0]).contextMenu('context-menu-1', obj);
}
```